# Gulp plugin to include/exclude line of JS code depending on task ran

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, gulp, uglifyjs

Are there any gulp plugins that when ran, can include/exclude a line of JavaScript.

For example, in one of my JS files I perform an HTTP GET to a local JSON file:

```
// To be used for localhost
$http.get('path-to-JSON-file.json')
    .success(function (data) {
        done(data);
    })
```

But when i move to my .NET server, i need this to be a call to a method:

```
// To be used for .NET
$http.get('/MyData/GetMyDataJson').success(function (data) {
    .success(function (data) {
        done(data);
    })
```

So, I'm happy to create 2 separate scripts tasks, one for a localhost version, and one for .NET.

I could use `gulp-replace`, but I *really* don't want to be placing code in my gulp.js file

Comment: Even if there is, it would not be a good practice due to maintenance issues.

Comment: @AnPhan - what would be the best way then? Im using Angular too.

Comment: Maybe you can use a configuration file for these? Or have your task run the code with dev environment variables?

Comment: @Oleg - a config file sounds the best way to go, could you explain how to have a config file work with Gulp?

Comment: @OamPsy Angular? I'd suggest [gulp-ng-constant](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ng-constant) then ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like Mustache to generate your code, eg something like this:

Your main file

```
$http.get('{{action_get_data}}').success(function (data) {
    .success(function(data) { 
        done(data);
})
```

Your gulp file:

```
var env="node";

var data={
    "node":{"action_get_data":"path-to-JSON-file.json"}
    ".NET":{"action_get_data":"/MyData/GetMyDataJson"}
};

gulp.src("./templates/*.mustache")
    .pipe(mustache(data[env]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
```

**Note:** However, there's a bit of overhead with this: you need to declare the variables in your file, fill an array in the gulpfile, wait for compilation everytime.

You can also use the same codebase and just use variables for the things that change between the different versions of the environment.

**Note2:** You can also fetch the environment data from a config file like this:

```
var data= require('data.json');
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "node":{"action_get_data":"path-to-JSON-file.json"}
    ".NET":{"action_get_data":"/MyData/GetMyDataJson"}
}
```